# error update my table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  CREATE TABLE LOCATION(
   street_address VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
    postal_code    VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
   city           VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
   state_province VARCHAR(25)       NULL,
 country_name   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT LOCATION_PK PRIMARY KEY(street_address, postal_code, city, 
 country_name),
  CONSTRAINT LOCATION_CK UNIQUE(street_address, city, state_province, 
   country_name),
  CONSTRAINT LOCATION_FK FOREIGN KEY(country_name)
      REFERENCES COUNTRY(country_name) );


  CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  street_address VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
postal_code    VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
 city           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 country_name   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
manager_id     DECIMAL(6)       NULL,
CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(department_name),
CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(street_address, postal_code, city, 
country_name)
    REFERENCES LOCATION(street_address, postal_code, city, country_name) );


 CREATE TABLE COUNTRY(
 country_name    VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
   region_name     VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_PK PRIMARY KEY(country_name),
   CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_FK FOREIGN KEY(region_name)
     REFERENCES REGION(region_name) );
```

I need to update my department Accounting has been moved to a new location. The new address is 3 Subang 1, Subang Jaya, Petaling Jaya, Malaysia. Post code is 47500. I already join those 3 table and yet it still cannot work. Why? Here is my sql update code :

```
  UPDATE DEPARTMENT a
 INNER JOIN LOCATION b ON a.street address = b.street address
  AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
    AND a.city=b.city
  AND a.country_name = b.county_name
  JOIN COUNTRY c
  on b.country_name = c.country_name
  SET a.street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ',
 b.street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ',
 a.postal_code = '31546',
 b.postal_code = '31546',
 a.city = 'PETALING JAYA ',
  b.city = 'PETALING JAYA ',
  a.country_name = 'MALAYSIA',
  b.country_name = 'MALAYSIA',
   c.country_name = 'MALAYSIA'
  WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'Accounting';
```

It say cannot update, foreign key fails. cannot delete or update a parent row: a
foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 0):

you have to omit the last comma before `where` clause:

```
....
b.country_name = 'MALAYSIA' --no comma here 
WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'Accounting';
```

Comment: sry i forget to add one more c.country name = malaysia

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tables, you need an alias.column on that last line

WHERE a.department_name = 'Accounting'

Answer (score 0):

I had to make couple of assumptions from your posted questions. 
let us know if the assumptions are incorrect.
First, I had to create another table [REGION] based on your foreign-key reference from [COUNTRY_FK].

```
CREATE 
TABLE   REGION (
    region_name     VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT REGION_PK PRIMARY KEY(region_name)
);
```

Next I restructured your update sql statement based on your original [UPDATE] to update table [DEPARTMENT]

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT 
  SET 
        street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ',
        postal_code    = '31546',
        city           = 'PETALING JAYA ',
        country_name   = 'MALAYSIA'
FROM  DEPARTMENT a
INNER 
JOIN LOCATION b  ON  a.street_address = b.street_address
                 AND a.postal_code    = b.postal_code
                 AND a.city           = b.city
                 AND a.country_name   = b.country_name
JOIN COUNTRY c   ON  b.country_name   = c.country_name
WHERE a.department_name = 'Accounting';
```

If you are trying to update multiple tables, you can construct your updates within a [TRANSACTION] statement.